If $A,B\subset[1,n]$ and $|A|>\frac{n}{2}$, then is $|(2A-B)\cap [1,n]|\geq|B|$?
Let $[1,n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. For two subsets $A,B\subset [1,n]$, define $2A-B=\{2a-b|a\in A, b\in B\}$.

If $A,B\subset[1,n]$ and $|A|>\frac{n}{2}$, then is $|(2A-B)\cap [1,n]|\geq|B|$?

I have tried some example constructions and it seems that if $A,B\subset[1,n]$ and $|A|>\frac{n}{2}$, then $|(2A-B)\cap [1,n]|\geq|B|$.
However, I have found it hard to prove this. The classic lower bound of $|2A-B|\geq |A|+|B|-1$ does not account for how many terms are in $[1,n]$.
This would be tight, as if we take $A=[1,\frac{n}{4}]\cup[\frac{3n}{4}+1,n]$ and $B=[n-|B|+1,n]$ then $|A|=\frac{n}{2}$ and:

For $|B|\geq\frac{n}{2}+1$, you get $|(2A-B)\cap [1,n]|=|B|-2$

For $|B|=\frac{n}{2}$, you get $|(2A-B)\cap [1,n]|=|B|-1$


For the same $A$ and $B=[\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2}+1]$, we have $|(2A-B)\cap [1,n]|=0<|B|$.
Additionally, if you take $A=[1,\frac{n}{4}]\cup[\frac{3n}{4},n]$ and $B=[n-|B|+1,n]$, then $|A|=\frac{n}{2}+1$ and:

For $|B|\geq \frac{n}{2}+1$, you get $|(2A-B)\cap [1,n]|=|B|$

For $|B|\leq \frac{n}{2}$, you get $|(2A-B)\cap [1,n]|>|B|$


I would appreciate any suggestions on how to approach this.

Presumably by $[1,n]$ you mean ${1,2,\dots,n}.$ Bad to use ambiguous notation before clarifying anythimg about context.

For $n=3$, let $A={1,3}$ and $B={2}$.

If $|A|>\frac{n}{2}$ then $|(2A-B)\cap[1,n]|\geq |B|$ if $n$ is even and $|(2A-B)\cap[1,n]|\geq |B|-1$ if $n$ is odd.
Let $n$ be even.
As $|A|>\frac{n}{2}$,there must exist $a_1,a_2\in A$ such that $a_1-a_2=\frac{n}{2}$ by the pigeon hole principle. So $2a_1-2a_2=n$. Then $2a_1-b_1\neq 2a_2-b_2$ for any $b_1,b_2\in B$, as $n=2a_1-2a_2=b_1-b_2<n$ is a contradiction. Clearly $2a_1-b_1\neq 2a_1-b_2$ and $2a_2-b_1\neq 2a_2-b_2$ for all $b_1\neq b_2\in B$.
As $2a_1,2a_2\in [2,2n]$ and $2a_1-2a_2=n$, we must have $2a_1\in[n+2,2n]$. Then for every $b\in B$ we have $2a_1-b\in [2,2n-1]$.
Therefore, either $2a_1-b\in[2,n]$ or $2a_1-b\in[n+1, 2n-1]$ in which case $2a_2-b=2a_1-b-n\in[1, n-1]$.
So for every $b$, either $2a_1-b$ or $2a_2-b$ is in $[1,n]$ and all of these terms are distinct. This gives us $|(2A-B)\cap[1,n]|\geq |B|$.
Let $n$ be odd.
We will prove that if $|A|\geq \frac{n+1}{2}$ then there must exist $a_1,a_2\in A$ such that either $a_1-a_2=\frac{n+1}{2}$ or $a_1-a_2=\frac{n-1}{2}$. Assume the contrary, that there are no such $a_1,a_2\in A$. As the terms in $A$ avoid differences equal to $\frac{n+1}{2}$, we can partition $A$ into sets so that at most 1 term in each of them can be in $A$:
$$\{1,\frac{n+3}{2}\}, \{2,\frac{n+5}{2}\}, \{3,\frac{n+7}{2}\}, \ldots, \{\frac{n-1}{2},n\},\{\frac{n+1}{2}\}.$$
As there are $\frac{n+1}{2}$ sets and $|A|\geq \frac{n+1}{2}$, we see that $|A|=\frac{n+1}{2}$ and exactly 1 term from each set must be in $A$. This implies that $\frac{n+1}{2}$ is in $A$.
Similarly, as the terms in $A$ avoid differences equal to $\frac{n-1}{2}$, we see that at most 1 term in each of the following sets can be in $A$:
$$\{1,\frac{n+1}{2}\}, \{2,\frac{n+3}{2}\}, \{3,\frac{n+5}{2}\}, \ldots, \{\frac{n-1}{2},n-1\},\{\frac{n+1}{2},n\}.$$
However, as $\frac{n+1}{2}$ is in $A$, neither $1$ or $n$ can be in $A$. Therefore, at most 1 term in each of the following sets can be in $A\backslash \frac{n+1}{2}$:
$$\{2,\frac{n+3}{2}\}, \{3,\frac{n+5}{2}\}, \ldots, \{\frac{n-1}{2},n-1\}.$$
As $|A\backslash \frac{n+1}{2}|=\frac{n+1}{2}-1=\frac{n-1}{2}$ and there are $\frac{n-3}{2}$ sets, we have reached a contradiction.
So assume we have $a_1,a_2\in A$ such that $a_1-a_2=\frac{n+1}{2}$. Then for $b_1,b_2\in B$, we see that $2a_1-b_1\neq 2a_2-b_2$ as otherwise $b_1-b_2=n+1$. Clearly $2a_1-b_1\neq 2a_1-b_2$ and $2a_2-b_1\neq 2a_2-b_2$ for all $b_1\neq b_2\in B$.
As $2a_1,2a_2\in[2,2n]$ and $2a_1-2a_2=n+1$, we must have $2a_1\in[n+3,2n]$. Then for every $b\in B$ we have $2a_1-b\in[3,2n-1]$.
Therefore, either $2a_1-b\in[3,n]$ or $2a_1-b\in[n+2, 2n-1]$ in which case $2a_2-b=2a_1-b-(n+1)\in[1,n-2]$ or $2a_1-b=n+1$.
So for every $b$, either $2a_1-b$ or $2a_2-b$ is in $[1,n]$ and all of these terms are distinct, unless $2a_1-b=n+1$ in which case $2a_2-b=0$. This gives us $|(2A-B)\cap[1,n]|\geq |B|-1$.
Finally, assume we have $a_1,a_2\in A$ such that $a_1-a_2=\frac{n-1}{2}$. Then for $b_1,b_2\in B$, we see that $2a_1-b_1=2a_2-b_2$ implies that $b_1-b_2=n-1$ which means $b_1=n$ and $b_2=1$.
As $2a_1,2a_2\in[2,2n]$ and $2a_1-2a_2=n-1$, we must have $2a_1\in[n+1,2n]$. Then for every $b\in B$ we have $2a_1-b\in[1,2n-1]$.
Therefore, either $2a_1-b\in[1,n]$ or $2a_1-b\in[n+1, 2n-1]$ in which case $2a_2-b=2a_1-b-(n-1)\in[2,n]$.
So for every $b$, either $2a_1-b$ or $2a_2-b$ is in $[1,n]$ and all of these terms are distinct, unless $1,n\in B$ in which case $2a_1-n=2a_2-1$. This gives us $|(2A-B)\cap[1,n]|\geq |B|-1$.
So if $|A|\geq \frac{n+1}{2}$, we have $a_1,a_2\in A$ such that $a_1-a_2=\frac{n+1}{2}$ or $a_1-a_2=\frac{n-1}{2}$. Therefore $|2A-B|\geq |B|-1$.
This can be seen to be tight by considering $A=[1,\frac{n-1}{4}]\cup[\frac{3n+1}{4},n]$ and $B=[\frac{n-1}{2},n]$. Here, $|A|=\frac{n+1}{2}$ and $|(2A-B)\cap[1,n]|=|B|-1$.

Is $n$ even? Because if it isn't, and by $[1,n]$ you mean ${1,\ldots,n}$, then $A\subseteq\Bbb N$ and $a_1-a_2\ne\frac{n}2,\forall a_1,a_2\in A$. On the other hand, if you mean $[1,n]$ as a segment of $\Bbb R$, $A:=\left[1,\frac{n}2\right]$ is a subset of $[1,n]$ and, yet, $|a_1-a_2|\le\frac{n}2-1<\frac{n}2,\forall a_1,a_2\in A$.
